# Unresolved import of render from django.shortcuts

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm using django in eclipse, trying to strap a django Framework onto a Google App Engine Backbone as per the following tut:
http://django-appengine.com/post/37778427717/create-a-simple-guestbook-application#disqus_thread

An error with the following line comes up:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

The error:

Unresolved import: 
 render

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Guidance: ignore Eclipse errors like this. Even better, don't use an IDE. They're not suited to dynamic languages like Python.

Comment: If you refer to external pages, please consider rewriting the essential part as this site might be gone in the future, rendering your post at least less useful.